# .NET HTTP POST request observer

Tags: c#, .net, http, system.diagnostics

I want to log all HTTP requests done by `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` in my application. Important note: I also need to log requests done by third-party packages implemented on top of `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. Which means I can't do some tricks directly on `HttpClient` instance.

So far I found two ways to do that: `System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventListener` and `IObserver<DiagnosticListener> / IObserver<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`. The first one gives less info, like schema, HTTP version, URL and query parameters. The second one gives more info, including HTTP headers. However none of them can observe POST request body, which in my case is the major part I need.

I think it's because POST body isn't something you can capture at once - the body can be really big, and under the hood it is usually implemented in a stream way. So such kind of observer also should observe in a stream way somehow.

Is that possible? PS: HTTP proxy on top of the application is not an option - most of requests are HTTPS, so I can't look inside their content outside of the application.

Comment: I don't know how to do that in code, but I just want to point out that it's pretty trivial to make a proxy responsible for the entire HTTPS flow including certificate management and traffic encryption, while keeping the traffic between the proxy and the app unencrypted. In fact, this is what Microsoft actually recommends: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev thank you for the link. Still, this won't cover all possble cases. For example, when you use third-party package which doesn't give you an option to configure URL manually so you can't replace https:// with http://

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this can be using middleware.

```
 public class DiagnosticsMiddleware
     {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<DiagnosticsMiddleware> _logger;
      
        public DiagnosticsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, 
                                 ILogger<DiagnosticsMiddleware> logger)
       {
          _next = next;
          _logger = logger;
       }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
         // YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC HERE, if any.
        }
    }
```

And registering it in Startup as below

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
    app.UseMiddleware<DiagnosticsMiddleware>();
  }
```